# I don't know how to parse this nested json

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm trying to parse this JSON using. However, I don't know how to parse "children". How can I map it to a class ?

I created a class to parse "displayProperties" but I don't know how to parse "children"

```
{
  "displayProperties": {
    "description": "",
    "name": "Les Ténèbres",
    "icon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/39ba3c78d0ad06c0728374d591c65821.png",
    "hasIcon": true
  },
  "originalIcon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/39ba3c78d0ad06c0728374d591c65821.png",
  "rootViewIcon": "/common/destiny2_content/icons/39ba3c78d0ad06c0728374d591c65821.png",
  "nodeType": 1,
  "scope": 1,
  "objectiveHash": 4168198558,
  "children": {
    "presentationNodes": [
      {
        "presentationNodeHash": 655926402
      },
      {
        "presentationNodeHash": 2082711113
      },
      {
        "presentationNodeHash": 2474271317
      }
    ],
    "collectibles": [],
    "records": []
  }
}
```

```
abstract class DestinyObject(json : String) : JSONObject(json){

    fun optDisplayProperties() : DisplayProperties{
        val json_object : DisplayProperties = this.optJSONObject("displayProperties") as DisplayProperties
        return json_object
    }
}
class DisplayProperties(json : String) : JSONObject(json){
    val name = this.optString("name")
    val icon = this.optString("icon")
    val description = this.optString("description")

}
```

Comment: It is a JSONObject with a JSONArrays `presentationNodes`, `collectibles`, and `records` inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create you Model class as below:

```
class Model(
    val displayProperties: DisplayProperties,
    val originalIcon: String,
    val rootViewIcon: String,
    val nodeType: String,
    val scope: String,
    val objectiveHash: Long,
    val children: Children
)

class Children(
    val presentationNodes: List<Any>,
    val collectibles: List<Any>,
    val records: List<Any>
)

class DisplayProperties(
    val description: String,
    val name: String,
    val icon: String,
    val hasIcon: Boolean
)
```

If you want to use any other model instead of **Any**, then you have to create this model also. Hope this will help you. In addition with this you may use JSON Parser library like **GSON** to parse the JsonObject. For the above JSON object the code looks like:

```
Gson().fromJson(json, Model::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter every object alone on any Json parsing website and can use 
 `Gson().fromJson(json, Model::class.java)` 
in your code